# select single row from table for a particular column combination

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table as below

Id... ColA... ColB... Isdefault

---

1...      100...    96...   1
2...      100...    96...   0
3...      101...    98...   0
4...      102...    99...   1

I want to have a select statement, where for a particular combination of ColA and ColB, I should get only one Row with the condition that if Isdefault with values both 0 and 1 present for a particular ColA,ColB combination, I should Only select one row with Isdefault=1 .

The output should look like below:

Id... ColA... ColB... Isdefault

---

1...      100...    96...   1
3...      101...    98...   0
4...      102...    99...   1

Note: Row with Id=2 is not present in the output because the same combination of ColA and ColB exists with isdefault=1

kindly help, thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table(Id int, ColA int, ColB int, Isdefault bit);
insert into @t values
(1, 100, 96, 1),
(2, 100, 96, 0),
(3, 101, 98, 0),
(4, 102, 99, 1);

with cte as
(
select *, row_number() over(partition by ColA, ColB order by Isdefault desc) rn
from @t
)

select Id, ColA, ColB, Isdefault
from cte
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: It woked for me, thanx for the help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that every pair of (ColA,ColB) has only two possible values (0,1), you can use an ANTI SEMI JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    Id, ColA, ColB, Isdefault
FROM
    @t t1
WHERE
    Isdefault = 1
OR (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1                   -- Implicit Isdefault=0 here
                FROM   @t t2
                WHERE  t2.ColA = t1.ColA
                AND    t2.ColB = t1.ColB
                AND    Isdefault = 1));
```

```
| Id | ColA | ColB | Isdefault |
|----|------|------|-----------|
| 1  | 100  | 96   | 1         |
| 3  | 101  | 98   | 0         |
| 4  | 102  | 99   | 1         |
```